# Why I am getting an error "Output Limit Exceeded" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list, palindrome

I am trying to solve a problem of `LinkedList` on leetcode in javascript language but out of `86` test cases `74` cases are passed but at `75` I am getting an error `Output Limit Exceeded`.

Problem:

```
Given the head of a singly linked list, return true if it is a palindrome.
```

Examples:

```
Input: head = [1,2,2,1]
Output: true

Input: head = [1,2]
Output: false
```

My code:

```
let array = [];
let list = head;
while (list) {
  array.push(list.val)
  console.log("array1", array)
  list = list.next;
}

let list2 = head;
while (list2) {
  let out = array.pop()
  if (out === list2.val) {
    list2 = list2.next;
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

return true
```

`Last executed input:`
[3,8,9,3,2,8,9,1,8,9,9,8,5,2,5,4,4,4,3,9,7,5,0,5,8,6,3,3,8,0,7,3,7,7,1,1,1,7,0,2,8,1,8,7,2,9,5,2,9,7,4,8,...]

I am not able to understand why I am getting a `Limit exceeded error`? Is it due to too many inputs? Or Issue is in my code? If the issue is with inputs then How can I solve this problem in Javascript?

Comment: push and pop on an array is probably causing the time issue. You may want to try a different approach.

Comment: Having a console.log in your loop is going to slow down the process too.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log` is trapped by the LeetCode framework, and as your first loop calls it in *every* iteration, this is slowing down the process significantly.

Just remove the `console.log`.

As a follow-up: try to find a solution where you do not copy every value into an array, which requires O(n) extra space. Instead, try to do it with  O(1) extra space.